# Attachments in QBO quick books online

Tags: php, quickbooks-online

ALL,
    I am using QBO V3 for PHP.  I only have limited php knowledge and don't know anything about XML items and JSON etc.  I built a site that interfaces with quick books online and so far I can do time tracking, customer adds etc.  I need to be able to send attachments to Quick books online and can not find a simple example IN PHP.  This is a similiar format I use for the items I created above, but there is no example on attachements.  Their help guide doesn't yeild much either.

```
// Load the OAuth information from the database
    if ($Context = $IPP->context())
{
    // Set the IPP version to v3 
    $IPP->version(QuickBooks_IPP_IDS::VERSION_3);

    $ItemService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Item();

    $Item = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Item();

    $Item->setName('My Item');
    $Item->setType('Inventory');
    $Item->setIncomeAccountRef('53');

    if ($resp = $ItemService->add($Context, $realm, $Item))
    {
        print('Our new Item ID is: [' . $resp . ']');
    }
    else
    {
        print($ItemService->lastError($Context));
    }


    print('<br><br><br><br>');
    print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    print('Request [' . $IPP->lastRequest() . ']');
    print("\n\n\n\n");
    print('Response [' . $IPP->lastResponse() . ']');
    print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");

}
```